# Talking on the phone, or to the phone?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I want to know whether I can ask a question like

> Have you finished talking **on** the phone?

or should it be

> Have you finished talking **to** the phone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go with

> Have you finished talking on the phone?

because it has the meaning of

> Have you finished talking (to another person) on the phone?

Your other sentence

> Have you finished talking to the phone?

means that someone is talking to the physical object that is the phone - not to another person.

In this context, the preposition "to" is used to show who or what is being talked to.